# How to add a string to my blog post path instead of integer with get_absolute_url in django?

Tags: python, django, url

I'm working on a simple blog project and have been following Corey Schafer on YouTube. In the tutorials, he creates new blog posts with integers (e.g. /blog/1, /blog/2, and so on), but I would like to create my post path with strings (like blog/my-blog-post, /blog/new-blog-post). I'm pretty new to python and django and I've tried some things with little luck. Any tips on how to do this?

Models:

```
class BloggPost(models.Model):
    tittel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    innhold = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='blogg_foto')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tittel

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BloggPostListViewHome, BloggPostListView, BloggPostDetailView
from . import views

path('blogg/<int:pk>/', BloggPostDetailView.as_view(), name='bloggpost-detail'),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `slug` field, for example with an [**`AutoSlugField`**](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField) from the [**`django-autoslug`** package [readthedocs]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You can install that in the virtual environment with:

```
pip install django-autoslug
```

then you can add an `AutoSlugField` to your model with:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class BloggPost(models.Model):
    tittel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='tittel')
    innhold = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='blogg_foto')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tittel

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

In your `urls.py` you then define a pattern with:

```
path('blogg/<slug:slug>/', BloggPostDetailView.as_view(), name='bloggpost-detail'),
```

Class-based views with a `SingleObjectMixin`, such as a `DetailView` and an `UpdateView`, will perform filtering automatically on a slug if a slug field exists in the URL patterns.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 with the blog path integer still. Is there anywhere I need to import the SingleObjectMixin?

Comment: @AndréKrosby: no, likely you need to repopulate your database, likely at the moment the slugs are empty? Did you alter the `get_absolute_url`?

Comment: @AndreKrosby: well you need to alter the `path` as well, and look if the `slug` column is populated in the database, likely you should make a new `BloggPost`

Comment: I changed the 'bloggpost-detail' in my urls to 'post-detail' and that worked. My HTML url is ```{% url 'post-detail' bloggpost.id %}```, should that now be ```bloggpost.slug?```

Comment: @AndréKrosby: yes, although it iis probably better to replace the `{% url ... %}`s with `{{ blogpost.get_absolute_url }}` (without parenthesis).

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you very much! I'm noticing that Æ/Ø/Å (I'm on a Norwegian keyboard) gets cut from the string. Is there an easy way to replace it with AE/OE/AA so it's included in the path? If not, it's not really a big deal, thank you so much for your help :)!

Comment: @AndréKrosby: you can likely pass a `AutoSlugField(populate_from='tittel', slugify=slugify)` with `from django.utils.text import slugify`. Although I did not test this.